# Proving global minimum by lower bound of 2-variable function $f(x,y)=x^4+2x^2y+y^2-4x^2-8x-8y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization, maxima-minima

I would like to prove that the following function $f :\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ has a **global minimum**:

> $f(x,y)=x^4+2x^2y+y^2-4x^2-8x-8y=(x^2+y)^2-4(x^2+2x+2y)$

$f$ has strict local minimum at
$f(1,3)=-20$

I think that what I need to show is that $-20$ is a lower bound of this function, and then conclude that's a global minimum, but I didn't manage to do so.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: $x^2-4x^2$? Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: @lonestudent you are right, fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the stationary points:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=4x^3+4xy-8x-8 \\[6px]
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=2x^2+2y-8
\end{align}
At a critical point $y=4-x^2$ and also
$$
x^3+x(4-x^2)-2x-2=0
$$
that is, $x=1$, that implies $y=3$.

Since clearly the function is upper unbounded on the line $y=0$, we just need to show it is lower bounded. Conjecturing that the stationary point is a minimum, we have $f(1,3)=-20$, we need to see whether $f(x,y)\ge-20$.

Now let's try completing the square in
$$
y^2+2(x^2-4)y+x^4-4x^2-8x+20
$$
Since $(x^2-4)^2=x^4-8x^2+16$, we have
$$
f(x,y)+20=(y+x^2-4)^2+4x^2-8x+4=(y+x^2-4)^2+4(x-1)^2
$$
which is everywhere nonnegative, so we proved that $f(x,y)\ge-20$.

Answer (score 4):

My favorite way,

$$f(x,y)+20=y^2+y(2x^2-8)+x^4-4x^2-8x+20$$

$$\begin{align}\Delta_{\text{half}}&=(x^2-4)^2-(x^4-4x^2-8x+20)\\
&=-4(x-1)^2≤0.\end{align}$$

This means, $f(x,y)+20≥0.$

Hence, for minimum of $f(x,y)+20$,  we need to take $x=1$ and $y=4-x^2$, which gives $f(x,y)+20=0.$

Finally, we deduce that

$$\min\left\{f(x,y)+20\right\}=0~ \\
\text {at}~ (x,y)=(1,3)$$

$$\min\left\{f(x,y)\right\}=-20~ \\ \text {at}~ (x,y)=(1,3)$$

where $f(x,y)=x^4+2x^2y+y^2-4x^2-8x-8y.$

---

**Small Supplement:**

Using the formula

$$ay^2+by+c=a(y-m)^2+n$$

where $m=-\dfrac{b}{2a}, n=-\dfrac{\Delta}{4a}$

$$\begin{align}y^2+y(2x^2-8)+x^4-4x^2-8x+20=(y+x^2-4)^2+4(x-1)^2≥0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. What is $\Delta_\text{half}$? Didn't get you.

Comment: @Denni "half of discriminant" if $$ax^2+2kx+c=0$$ then we can use $\Delta=k^2-ac$

Comment: You are basically saying that if a function has a single local minima, it is global, but it is not true: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~tom.vogel/gallery/node16.html

Comment: @Michael I don't know multivariable calculus. Please show me only my algebraic errors/claims. Then you can downvote.

Comment: You don't have any algebraic mistakes but you need to show that the function is bounded from below because you may have a situation where $f \to -\infty$ for some path.

Comment: @Michael I could not fully understand.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong right now.

Comment: @Michael If one proves that $f(x,y)\ge-20$, then the function is lower bounded. The technique used here is a bit contrived, but not wrong.

Comment: @egreg thank you very much for explanation. I didn't get calculus lessons. I agree. Because, I knew $-20$ beforehand.  But I could use the constant $C$ instead of $-20$ to ensure that the $\Delta ≤0$...

Comment: +1: (also) to lone student's answer.  @Michael I agree that although lone student's analysis is both accurate and valid, I (for one) found it confusing.  I would have written it as $$f(x,y) + 20 = y^2 + y(2x^2 - 8) + (x^4 - 4x^2 - 8x + 20)$$ which equals $$[y + (x^2 - 4)]^2 + 4(x-1)^2.$$ Therefore, $[f(x,y) + 20]$ must have a global minimum when both $$y + (x^2 - 4) = 0 ~~\text{and}~~ (x-1) = 0.$$  lone student is welcome to use this comment to clarify his answer, if he wishes.

Comment: If I was using my previous comment, I would say that $[f(x,y) + 20]$ must be globally minimized at $x = 1$ and $y + (-3) = 0 \implies y = 3.$  In my opinion, that statement, in an of itself, is game over.

Comment: @user2661923 I think the answer seems good now.  Finally.:)

Comment: looks good, nice.

Comment: With the supplement it is much better, I changed my vote :)